# getElementsByClassName returning nothing

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am using the following script -

```
<HTML>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/xml; charset=windows-1252'>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function show(){
        var navLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
            var link = navLinks[i];
            var title = link.title;
            alert(title);
    }
}
    </script>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>Properties</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<button type="button" onClick="show()">Close</button>

<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>

<tr>
    <td>Contact</td>
    <td class="a">(01) 234 5678</td>
</tr>

</table>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

All I want to do is show an alert box showing `(01) 234 5678` however IE8 does nothing and Chrome shows a blank alert box.

I am new to Javascript but where am I going wrong?

Comment: May I suggest you switch to [JQuery](http://jquery.com/).
Then it's as simple as $('.a').each(function() { $(this).click(alert($(this).text())); })

Comment: IE8 does not support `getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: may i state that [jQuery is not the answer to everything](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif).

Comment: To pick up IE8 support, use `document.querySelectorAll('.a')` instead of `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: jQuery is not the answer to everything obviously (although it often may seem like it on this site..) but I have been faced with a similar problem and as for a selecting by class name jQuery's selectors make it somewhat easier

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't know it was frowned upon to suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to get the link title you need to get the innerHTML like this:

```
var title = link.innerHTML;
```

Comment: just an observation, even though this is correct, IE8 and below do not have browser-native support for getElementsByClassName()

Comment: correct, I am using Chrome however how would I resolve this issue?

Comment: @Jambo Really once you start getting into the world of trying to traverse and manipulate DOM elements, you really should consider using a framework like jQuery as it make operations like this really easy and takes care of the cross-browser issues for you (for the most part at least).

Answer (score 0):

I'm wrong. I use firebug and try console.log to output.
navLinks can get correct result

```
<td class="a">(01) 234 5678</td>
```

however you don't have title attribute, therefore nothing is returned.
try

```
<td class="a" title="(01) 234 5678">(01) 234 5678</td>
```

I get it work on my machine

Comment: The code is in a  function that's called when a button is clicked. It's not the problem.

Comment: To make the HTML show up in your answer, highlight it, and click the **`{}`** button above the edit area.